# Header Doesn't work inside an IF/ELSE

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm trying to prevent direct access to a the following file (and only allow access to those who submitted a form), Can someone tell what is wrong with this code?

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    header('HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed');

    } else {

if(isset($_POST['a'])){

    switch ($_POST['a']) {

    case "1":
        $var = "hey";
        break;

    case "2":
        $var = "now";
        break;

    default:
        $var = "other";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You are not closing the top if else statement

Comment: you have an error in the code.. close the else with `}` at the end of your code and I just checked on the firebug and I can see the response status as 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: do you mean add an additional single `}` at the end of the code? Dreamweaver alerts on a syntax error If I do that.

Comment: `} else {` is not closed in the supplied code as u gave.

Comment: If Dreamweaver is giving a syntax error then there is more code you are not showing us that is causing it. In the above code as is, the first if else statement needs closing at the end.

Comment: Your'e right, I've had a `}` at the very bottom of the page, thanks.

Comment: please see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809362/php-header-isnt-working-page-is-displayed-as-usual) as even with the fix, there's now another problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
   //header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");


    } else {

          if(isset($_POST['a'])){

          switch ($_POST['a']) {

                   case "1":
                            $var = "hey";
                            break;

                   case "2":
                            var = "now";
                            break;

                   default:
                            $var = "other";
                  }
          }
}
```

this will not print anything but will set the response header code. If you comment the current heder line and uncomment line with google url, it will take you to google web site. If there is no more code belove this code, than you can safely ignore php closing tag '?>'.