# PHP Header Isn't working - Page is displayed as usual

Tags: php

I'm trying to prevent direct access to a the following file (and only allow access to those who submitted a form), but when I go right to this file, Instead of 404 I'm seeing the file correctly. Can someone tell what is wrong with this code?

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  } else {
    if(isset($_POST['a'])){
      switch ($_POST['a']){
        case "1":
          $var = "hey";
          break;
        case "2":
          $var = "now";
          break;
        default:
          $var = "other";
      }
    }
  }
?>  
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    something
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `exit` after setting the header

Comment: You send the HTML anyway.

Comment: Should I also add `ob_end_clean();` like in that thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember to stop executing after you've called 404:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
exit(); // Stop Executing
```

If you don't, you'll be sending the 404 status code *and* the HTML, and most browsers would still display the HTML in that case. x

**To display an error page**

Make an error screen and put it in a file named something like, 404.php, then update the code to:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
include '404.php'; // Display the Not Found error
exit();            // Stop Executing
```

Comment: I've added it and now I get a blank page, why am I not getting the error page?

Comment: Internet Explorer displays a custom error page for 404's without content (known as a "friendly error message") but most other browsers will display what they want, ie a blank screen. If you want to make your own error page, I'd suggest creating one, putting it in a file named 404.php, then adding `include '404.php';`. I'll edit my answer to reflect this :) x

Answer (score 1):

Add **exit;** after the 404 header.

Really make sure there is nothing in front of the opening php tag *<?php*